# Is changing the image style causing the LoadEvent to be fired?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, onload

As far as I can tell, this change to the image style is causing the LoadEvent to be fired. Can someone confirm this? Explain this? This is GWT on Firefox 3.

```
Image image = new Image("image_src_URL");

image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        double ratio = 0.5;
        image.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(image.getWidth() * ratio, Style.Unit.PX);
        Window.alert("You are in onLoad");
    }
}
```

This code actually sits inside the onLoad method, and I can clearly see that it is entered twice. Any hints? Is there another way to resize the image that won't fire the event? `image.setWidth()` does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the `LoadHandler` to ever fire more than once?  You could de-register it:

```
new LoadHandler() {
  HandlerRegistration reg = image.addLoadHandler(this);

  @Override
  public void onLoad(LoadEvent evt) {
    reg.removeHandler();
    // Reset style
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, this is exactly what I need, because if it fires twice, the image is resized twice, which is wrong.